# Cant move a box from center of screen (like if is a column/row)

Tags: android, ios, react-native, mobile, expo

I was initially building a real-time chat application for the web, and when I switched to React Native for mobile development, I couldn't figure out how to move the user text boxes from the center of the screen. [The text boxes only move towards the edges when an excessively long message is entered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NdWuR.png).
I am trying to create a layout similar to WhatsApp, but [the box containing the user's content is not moving from the center of the screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cBX75.png). I want to move it to the borders. Additionally, on iOS, the box where I enter the message is being overlapped by the keyboard. How can I fix this? This is my first time working with React Native, so I'm not very familiar with it. Tried to use GPT, but it got worse.

**Chat.js**

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { View, Text, TextInput, TouchableOpacity, StyleSheet, ScrollView } from 'react-native';

export default function Chat({ socket, username }) {
  const [currentMessage, setCurrentMessage] = useState('');
  const [messageList, setMessageList] = useState([]);

  const enviarMensagem = async () => {
    if (currentMessage !== '') {
      const messageData = {
        user: username,
        message: currentMessage,
        time: new Date(Date.now()).getHours() + ':' + new Date(Date.now()).getMinutes(),
      };
      await socket.emit('enviar_mensagem', messageData);
      setMessageList((prevMessageList) => [...prevMessageList, messageData]);
      setCurrentMessage('');
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    socket.on('receber_mensagem', (data) => {
      setMessageList((prevMessageList) => [...prevMessageList, data]);
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <ScrollView style={styles.messageContainer}>
        {messageList.map((message, index) => (
          <View 
            key={index}
            style={[
              styles.messageItem,
              message.user === username ? styles.userMessage : styles.otherMessage,
            ]}
          >
            <Text style={styles.username}>{message.user}</Text>
            <Text style={styles.messageText}>{message.message}</Text>
            <Text style={styles.time}>{message.time}</Text>
          </View>
        ))}
      </ScrollView>
      <View style={styles.inputContainer}>
        <TextInput
          style={styles.input}
          placeholder="Digite uma mensagem..."
          value={currentMessage}
          onChangeText={setCurrentMessage}
          textAlign="right"
        />
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.sendButton} onPress={enviarMensagem}>
          <Text style={styles.sendButtonText}>Enviar</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#f5f5f5',
    justifyContent: "center", 
    alignItems: "center",
  },
  messageContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    paddingHorizontal: 16,
    paddingTop: 16,
  },
  messageItem: {
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    borderRadius: 8,
    padding: 8,
    marginBottom: 8,
  },
  userMessage: {
    alignSelf: 'flex-end',
    backgroundColor: '#dcf8c6',
  },
  otherMessage: {
    alignSelf: 'flex-start',
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
  },
  username: {
    fontSize: 16,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    marginBottom: 4,
  },
  messageText: {
    fontSize: 14,
    marginBottom: 4,
  },
  time: {
    fontSize: 12,
    color: '#888',
  },
  inputContainer: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
    padding: 8,
    borderTopWidth: 1,
    borderTopColor: '#ccc',
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
  },
  input: {
    flex: 1,
    height: 40,
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: '#ccc',
    borderRadius: 20,
    paddingHorizontal: 16,
    marginRight: 8,
  },
  sendButton: {
    backgroundColor: '#4caf50',
    borderRadius: 20,
    paddingVertical: 8,
  },
  sendButtonText: {
    color: '#fff',
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    fontSize: 16,
  },
});
```

**App.js**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { View, TextInput, Button } from "react-native";
import { io } from "socket.io-client";
import Chat from "./Chat";

const socket = io.connect("http://***.**.*.**:3001");

export default function App() {
  const [username, setUsername] = useState("");
  const [showChat, setShowChat] = useState(false);

  const entrarSala = () => {
    if (username !== "") {
      socket.emit("entrar_sala", "sala1");
      setShowChat(true);
    }
  };

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: "center", alignItems: "center" }}>
      {!showChat ? (
        <View>
          <TextInput
            style={{ height: 40, width: 200, borderColor: "gray", borderWidth: 1 }}
            placeholder="José..."
            onChangeText={(text) => setUsername(text)}
          />
          <Button title="Entrar no Chat" onPress={entrarSala} />
        </View>
      ) : (
        <Chat socket={socket} username={username} />
      )}
    </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: May be you need to add ```alignself:'center'``` in the ```messageItem``` styles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make the width of container "100%" and use KeyboardAvoidingView to animate input container while opening keyboard. Try this:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import {
  View,
  Text,
  TextInput,
  TouchableOpacity,
  StyleSheet,
  KeyboardAvoidingView,
  Dimensions,
  FlatList,
} from "react-native";

export default function Chat({ socket, username }) {
  const [currentMessage, setCurrentMessage] = useState("");
  const [messageList, setMessageList] = useState([]);

  const enviarMensagem = async () => {
    if (currentMessage !== "") {
      const messageData = {
        user: username,
        message: currentMessage,
        time:
          new Date(Date.now()).getHours() +
          ":" +
          new Date(Date.now()).getMinutes(),
      };
      await socket.emit("enviar_mensagem", messageData);
      setMessageList((prevMessageList) => [...prevMessageList, messageData]);
      setCurrentMessage("");
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    socket.on("receber_mensagem", (data) => {
      setMessageList((prevMessageList) => [...prevMessageList, data]);
    });
  }, []);

  const RenderMessage = (item) => {
    return (
      <View
        key={item.index}
        style={[
          styles.messageItem,
          item.item.user === username
            ? styles.userMessage
            : styles.otherMessage,
        ]}
      >
        <Text style={styles.username}>{item.item.user}</Text>
        <Text style={styles.messageText}>{item.item.message}</Text>
        <Text style={styles.time}>{item.item.time}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  };
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <KeyboardAvoidingView style={styles.avoidingView} behavior="padding">
        <FlatList
          data={messageList}
          renderItem={RenderMessage}
          keyExtractor={(item) => item.message}
          showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
          inverted={true}
          scrollEnabled={true}
          style={{
            width: "100%",
          }}
        />
        <View style={styles.inputContainerView}>
          <TextInput
            placeholder="Digite uma mensagem..."
            multiline={true}
            style={styles.inputContainer}
            autoFocus={true}
            value={currentMessage}
            onChangeText={setCurrentMessage}
          ></TextInput>

          <TouchableOpacity onPress={enviarMensagem}>
            <Text style={styles.sendButtonText}>Enviar</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      </KeyboardAvoidingView>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "#f5f5f5",
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
  },
  messageContainer: {
    paddingHorizontal: 16,
    paddingTop: 16,
    width: "100%",
  },
  messageItem: {
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
    borderRadius: 8,
    padding: 8,
    marginBottom: 8,
  },
  userMessage: {
    alignSelf: "flex-end",
    backgroundColor: "#dcf8c6",
  },
  otherMessage: {
    alignSelf: "flex-start",
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
  },
  username: {
    fontSize: 16,
    fontWeight: "bold",
    marginBottom: 4,
  },
  messageText: {
    fontSize: 14,
    marginBottom: 4,
  },
  time: {
    fontSize: 12,
    color: "#888",
  },
  inputContainerView: {
    flexDirection: "row",
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
    width: Dimensions.get("window").width,
    paddingBottom: Dimensions.get("window").height * 0.12,
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
    borderTopLeftRadius: 33,
    borderTopRightRadius: 33,
    borderColor: "#e7e9e9",
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderBottomColor: "white",
    padding: 20,
  },
  inputContainer: {
    backgroundColor: "#f4f4f4",
    borderRadius: 10,
    paddingBottom: 5,
    paddingTop: Platform.OS == "ios" ? 12 : 5,
    paddingHorizontal: 10,
    minHeight: 45,
    maxHeight: 70,
    textAlignVertical: "center",
    width: Dimensions.get("window").width * 0.75,
  },
  input: {
    flex: 1,
    height: 40,
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: "#ccc",
    borderRadius: 20,
    paddingHorizontal: 16,
    marginRight: 8,
  },
  sendButton: {
    backgroundColor: "#4caf50",
    borderRadius: 20,
    paddingVertical: 8,
  },
  sendButtonText: {
    color: "grey",
    fontWeight: "bold",
    fontSize: 16,
  },
  avoidingView: {
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "space-between",
    height: Dimensions.get("window").height * 0.9,
    width: "100%",
  },
});
```

Comment: nop it remains the same :/

Comment: i found a solution, in messageContainer i used minWidth: '100%' instead of width: "100%", thanks :D